# Store the results of the test sets executed from Quality Center when using RunTestSet.exe

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center

I have used RunTestSet utility using ant to run testsets from QC automatically. i need to save the test results in a location. Earlier i used RunResultsOption in vbscript and got the results. Now when using RunTestSet, how can i create a RunResultsOption with RunTestSet? Please guide me.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: Retagging with quality-center for you.

Answer (score 0):

So you gave up on the JavaScript eh? :)

Short answer: you can't do what you want using that utility. You're running QC testsets, so by definition you're storing the run results in QC and not locally.

RunTestSetScheduler (which I assume is what you're using) is an unsupported utility, more designed as a code sample to get you started on writing your own such utility.

If you want to store the results in a directory of your choosing, then you need to be driving QTP directly using the QTP API rather than the QC API, and not through QC testsets. I don't think you can have both. Of course, you can still store your scripts in QC, you just won't be accessing them via a testset.

If you really want to do this, then I recommend you take the plunge and start writing your own proper test runner. If you get the hang of it (and you have the time), you'll be able to do just about whatever you want to meet your test running needs. For various reasons I found tht QC did not meet my needs for running scripts and so wrote my own much more functional runner in C#, and I'm very satisfied with the results, so give it a try.